# Difference between Passkit and Applepay in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, wallet, passkit

I have to work on the digital wallet in Swift 3. I have seen so many tutorials. In some tutorials they are showing Apple pay and in some Passkit. I am very much confused.

Can anyone please clarify the doubt about it.

Also how to use digital wallet as an App?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Add content to Apple Wallet? What type of content? Credit Cards or Passes?

Answer (score 0):

There is far difference between Apple Pay and PassKit.

**ApplePay**

- Apple Pay is such inbuit application in iOS which keeps your card details.
- Within native app or in safari, when there is button like "Buy with Apple Pay"
- When you buy ( Online shopping ) with Apple pay, it will authorize you with your thumb verification.
- https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

**PassKit**

- Passkit is kind of digital wallet
- https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit

So select anyone of them or both as per your requirement.

In some tutorials when it is showing together that means Apple pay informations are coming from Passkit.

Comment: Digital wallet means what we can do with that.Only storing of our card deatils.That's it?